# Python ElementTree find first element

Tags: python

I need to get the first and only child element of a node and the child is guaranteed to be there. I could write something like this

```
def get_first(Node):
  for x in Node:
    return x
```

But I was hoping for something more elegant. Does anyone know of something?

Comment: Your code is plenty elegant. (`Node` defies expected naming conventions, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I personally don't see anything wrong with your code.  It is clean and will work for any iterable object.

Nevertheless, if you must do away with the for-loop, then you can use [`next`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#next):

```
def get_first(Node):  # Also, Node should be lowercase according to PEP 8
    return next(Node)
```

However, this will only work for iterators.  If `Node` is not an iterator, then you can make it one with [`iter`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#iter):

```
def get_first(Node):
    return next(iter(Node))
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried by index?

```
def get_first(node):
    return node[0]
```